# Is it possible to generate inferred mli files with oasis?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I realize you can generate the inferred mli files one by one using ocamlbuild xxx.inferred.mli but I would prefer this to be done automatically for me (too see which types ocaml infers and to use these mli's as a basis for my own). Of course I would like to skip modules for which I already specified the mli myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not possible by Oasis, and it is not a job of Oasis, since this is highly build system dependent.

You should think of making mli files from compiled interface files (.cmi) instead, since cmi's are already compiled and therefore build system independent. I do not know whether such a tool already exists or not, but it should be failrly easy for someone familiar with OCaml compiler internals, with the following functions:

- Cmi_format.read_cmi to load cmi files as signatures.
- Printtyp.signature to print the loaded singnatures in human readable form (=mli).

Comment: Ah so I guess it's impossible (impractical at least). Thanks anyway.

Comment: do.. `ocaml setup.ml -build [FULLPATH].inferred.mli`. This will build the project and generate the mli in the _build directory.